# Passport local strategy not being called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

**Update**: I have downloaded [express-4.x-local-example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example) and can't seem to get it working either. Is there something that I'm missing?

I'm trying to set a local strategy for passport but it's not being fired. After entering the credentials, the page redirects to failureRedirect.

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , mainRouter = require('./controllers/mainRouter');

mainRouter(app);
```

---

mainRouter.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , passport = require('passport')
    , passportConfig = require('../config/passport');

passportConfig(passport);

module.exports = (app) => {    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate(('local'), {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: 'login/',
        })
    );            
}
```

---

passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'},
        (email, password, done) => {
            console.log('This message is not being logged.');
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually calling the strategy in your mainRouter.js file.

Before the app.post, add `passport.use(passportConfig);`

Comment: I've tried this already, but got _Error: Authentication strategies must have a name_.

Isn't `passportConfig(passport)` supposed to load the strategy?

Comment: @AlPeterson it requires a name, because it is a local strategy. try `const passportStrat = passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'},
        (email, password, done) => {
            console.log('This message is not being logged.');
        })
    );`

Then:
`passport.use('basic', passportStrat);`